# Pagination in share Point 2013 using rest API

Tags: sharepoint, shared-libraries, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have one requirement to implement pagination in sharePoint 2013 using rest api.

I am currently using below query string for pagination:

```
var querystring="?$skiptoken=" + encodeURIComponent('Paged=TRUE&p_SortBehavior=0&p_ID=' + (startItemId-1) + '&$top=' + itemsCount);
```

It is working fine. But one of my client asking they want to display items and pagination based on order by start date.

I have tried with below querystring:

```
var querystring="?$skiptoken=" + encodeURIComponent('Paged=TRUE&p_SortBehavior=0&p_ID=' + (startItemId-1) + '&$top=' + itemsCount)+ "&$orderby=startdate ";
```

If I will give like this its not working. If i will give ID column instead of startdate its working fine.

Can any one suggest how to use startdate column in querystring while using skiptoken?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query like below. This should help.

var querystring="?$skiptoken=" + encodeURIComponent('Paged=TRUE&p_SortBehavior=0&p_ID=' + (startItemId-1) + '&$top=' + itemsCount + '&$orderby=startdate')

Thanks,
Danny
Please remember to mark as answer if it helps or vote if useful.